# Magento GetProductThumbnail doesn't work after upgrade

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I have upgraded from Magento 1.7.0.0 to 1.9.0.1 and after finally sorting out most of the issues I'm left with one I can't get around.

None of the thumbnail images on my product pages or in my cart work.  They just show the placeholder images, but no the placeholder images that I have set it is showing the default magento ones in the Skin folder.

I am using this to get the thumbnails,

```
echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(74, 89);
```

I am also having issues in other areas when I use this code,

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize(100,153)
```

If I use any other word other than "thumbnail" it works fine but as soon as I use thumbnail i get the same result, just the random placeholder images.

I'm running out of ideas as to why this isn't working now.

Edit:

Ok I thought I had it working but it turns out i'd just copied the cache folder over from the live site.  I've narrowed it down a bit then.  It seems like Magento is just refusing the generate the cache images for some reason but I have no idea why.  Permissions are all set on the folders and GD is running on the server as its the same as the live site.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for downvoting for no reason at all

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix my own issue.

Behind the scenes the "imagecopymerge" function was erroring in Gd2.php because it was being passed a string instead of a long as a value for watermark opacity.

After looking in the Magento config images were set for the watermarks but the opacity field was left blank.

Not sure why it errored as really the field should be able to be blank I suppose but nevermind.